# UPDATE ELSE INSERT Case sensitive?

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I need some help regarding the code for update else insert strategy in informatica.

I have data like below :

```
user id    role  date
a123456    abc   21/01/2019
A123456    abc   22/01/2019
```

primary keys in table is user id and role and we need to update the record with max date
Though i was expecting it as different record because user id is in lower case and upper case but it was showing output as :

```
A123456    abc   22/01/2019
```

however i was expecting both the rows.Please suggest

Comment: Please add more information regarding your source/target, transformations you have applied, session properties you have set etc.

Comment: Maybe it's better to unify keys, You can try to add :  UPPER( )  in flow

Answer (score 0):

If the target table is oracle, check the case sensitivity by executing this query:

SELECT CASE WHEN 'test'='TEST' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS TEST_COL FROM DUAL;

Based on the result, You can alter the session and change the NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS (NLS_COMP and NLS_SORT values) values to treat the strings as case insensitive and I believe that would solve your issue.